# updating frequency of values occurred in multiple HashMap using a 2D array in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, hashmap

> {1=Chips and Nuts, 2=Beer Only, 3=Party Room, 4=Custom, Printed, 5=Band, 6=Water and Soap}
>
> {1=Finger-Food, 2=Cocktail, 3=Party Room, 4=Custom, Handmade, 5=DJ, 6=Specialized Materials}
>
> {1=Chips and Nuts, 2=Beer Only, 3=Common Room, 4=Plain, 5=DJ, 6=Water and Soap}

In Java 8, I'm trying to count the values' occurrences in multiple HashMap like these listed above using a 2D int array, and I want to do it dynamically, like as every time a HashMap pops out, I'll update this frequency table in that 2D array.

The keys in these HashMap is fixed, but I don't know which values the HashMap could generate, its within a finite set, but that info is unknown.

So, can this be done easily using a 2D int array? or there is more appropriate way to do this?

My first question as a beginner, thx for your attention :)